# Is there a (free/open source) black and white emoji font?

Tags: fonts, open-source, font-face, unicode, emoji

I wonder if there is a free black and white emoji font out there. All of the ones I have seen are in full color, but there are the two Unicode glyphs ☺, ☻, that's all I have seen.

Comment: What stops you form making your own?

Comment: See more on Stack Overflow: [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32413731/3416774)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is copied from [Black and white emoji fonts – enfascination](https://enfascination.com/weblog/post/1809)

---

Noto Emoji Font
Google has a fully internationalized font, Noto, whose emoji font has a black and white version:
https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/tree/master/fonts
The smiley’s are blobs.

EmojiOne
EmojiOne is a color font with black and white fallbacks. I couldn’t figure out how to trigger the fallbacks, but I found an early pre-color version of EmojiOne:
https://github.com/eosrei/emojione

Android Emoji
Not sure why, but one of Android’s main Emoji fonts is black and white
https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/tree/master/Android/assets/fonts
The smiley’s are androids.

GNU’s FreeFont
FreeFont is black and white.
http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/?C=M;O=D

SymbolA
SymbolA is a black and white Linux font with nearly full Unicode support:
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode
http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/

EmojiSymbols
A free font by an independent designer.
http://emojisymbols.com/
You can convert from woff to ttf here

Microsoft Segoe UI Symbol
Microsoft has a very high-quality emoji set in its Segoe UI Symbol/Emoji font. And because of copyright law, in which things have to be copyrighted separately for different uses, there shouldn’t be anything keeping us from using it to create printed type:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe
http://www.myfontfree.com/segoeuiemoji-myfontfreecom126f132714.htm

FireFoxEmoji
This might be from an old pre color version:
https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/moztt/blob/master/FirefoxEmoji-1.6.7/FirefoxEmoji.ttf

Twitter’s Emoji font
Twitter open sources its emoji font. This doesn’t have a black and white version, but it does have black and white fallbacks. If I can figure out how to extract or trigger the fallbacks, this could be great.
https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji

There may be more at the bottom of this:
https://github.com/eosrei/emojione
and here
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts#Emoji_and_symbols

Comment: Ooker - Your comment about "`have to be copyrighted separately for different uses`" suggests a serious misunderstanding of copyright law. Copyright has nothing to do with forms of usage, only with creation and the rights of the creator to make copies and derivative works, or prevent same. Copyright holders can optionally *license* their creations with limitations on usage but that is a choice *they* make, not part of the law. In short all copyright says is "*You create it, you own it. You own it, you control what can be done with it.*" (at least under US law, not sure about int'l law)

Comment: actually I just copy from that blog, so it's not me. But thanks for the information anyway. A question: you say that copyright holders can prevent making copies. But I thought that there are open licenses that you can still have copyright on it?

Comment: Many people confuse licensing with copyright. Copyright is the legally **exclusive** right to create copies and derivative works (essentially modified copies) of something you created. These rights **automatically** exist the moment you create something that is eligible for copyright (somethings are not eligible). Said rights can be delegated to others which is called licensing (either for free or for a fee). Copyrights can also be transferred by the creator (again either for free or for a fee) to someone else such as an heir or an employer.

Comment: ah, so copyright is only about the author, and only about the original work, right? If I make a document, then I have a copyright for it. But if I copy it, do I still have the copyright for that copy? What if I allow others to copy it?

Comment: The b+w google noto emoji are hideous lol.

Comment: The ones [there](https://emojisymbols.com/emojilist.php) are pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

I went through all of the previously posted options, and the only emoji that has black and white emoji as well as being up-to-date with unicode (ie- having all current emoji) is this Opentype font version of Twemoji: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font. It is auto-generated from the color version though, so it's not as refined as some of the other less-complete emoji sets.

The difficulty is, the black and white versions of the emoji do not seem to be released as their own font or set of graphics. As far as I can tell, they are only accessible as a fallback in the "Opentype as SVG" font found on the releases page: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font/releases. In Photoshop, converting the text to outlines will give you the black and white version of the font, but beyond that I'm not sure how to access them directly.

EDIT: Someone has also posted all of the b&w emojis as individual SVGs here: https://github.com/youdly/twemoji-color-font/tree/v11-release/assets/builds/svg-bw Currently, I don't believe there is a font version of these.

Comment: I opened the font in FontForge (maybe relevant, an old version 24 sept 2017) and that only showed me the black and white versions. I could then go to 'generate fonts' and export a font with only the fallbacks as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Ooker provided a really nice list. One quality set that's missing from that list is [EmojiTwo](https://github.com/EmojiTwo/emojitwo/tree/master/svg_bw).

Also, if you're looking for specific symbols, [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) is a good resource for open-source black-and-white icons.